# OptionsParser execute methods?

Tags: ruby

I'm sorry if this is a blatantly obvious question, but optparse's documentation is downright awful and I can't seem to make sense of it. I just had a simple question. Can I execute a method using optparse like so:

```
dns = DNS.new

options = {}

optparse = OptionParser.new do |opts|
opts.banner = $usage

options[:standard] = false
opts.on( 'a', '--standard', 'Standard DNS Query' ) do
    options[:standard] = true
end

options[:mail] = false
opts.on( 'mx', '--mail', 'MX Server Query' ) do
    options[:mail] = true
end

options[:reverse] = false
opts.on( 'ptr', '--reverse', 'Reverse DNS Lookup' ) do
    options[:reverse] = true
end

opts.on( '-h', '--help', 'Display usage' ) do
    puts opts
    exit
end
end

optparse.parse!


ARGV.each do |arg|
    puts "Querying #{arg}"
    dns.a_records(arg) if options[:standard]
    dns.mx_records(arg) if options[:mail]
    dns.ptr_records(arg) if options[:reverse]
end
```

It doesn't seem like I can, or I'm doing it wrong. Because the only thing that actually happens is printing the string "Querying #{arg}."

Comment: You may be declaring your arguments incorrectly here. What does `--help` show? As far as I know, all arguments should follow the format like `-h` has, single-dash+single-letter and double-dash+multiple-letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example almost works for me. The only thing you need to change is to prepend "-" to short options names. I.e.

```
opts.on( '-a', '--standard', 'Standard DNS Query' )
```

instead of

```
opts.on( 'a', '--standard', 'Standard DNS Query' )
```

That way `<your_program> something -a` would have the `:standard` option defined. If you just keep `a` in `opts.on` it will be recognized as another `arg` in your cycle, not as an option.

Comment: How embarrassing, it's so simple. This was exactly the problem, thank you.